# How to get the original string from NSLocalizedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

In my Swift app I have `UIButton` with title

```
NSLocalizedString("Barrels", comment: "Default oil convert type")
```

In Russian it will be `"Баррели"`, but for the logic of application I need to get the original string `"Barrels"`.

For ex.:

```
let index: Int = find(converter.oilConvertTypes.keys.array, sender.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)!)!
```

Here I need to find the index of `oilConvertTypes` hash keys by the `UIButton`'s (`sender`) title. But title is in Russian and in `oilConvertTypes` all keys are in English.

Is it possible? Or I need to store original value in some separate `var`?

Thanks!

Comment: Your model is fundamentally flawed if you are using the title of the button as part of the logic.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple solution would be to create a custom `UIButton` subclass with an additional `NSString` property for the English title. When it is tapped you can cast `sender` to your subclass and check the value of this property.